# Table with headers and 3 left columns fixed?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap class .table-responsive and the table include an horizontal scrollbar sort of like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column ...</th>
                <th>Column n</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column ...</td>
                <td>Column n</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

but i need to make the headers and the first 3 columns freeze.
 I've tried some fiddle, css tricks and stuff i find, but that ruins the .table-responsive it seem that those examples only work for tables that fits in 100% browser width.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic can solve your problem.

```
<thead>
     <tr>
         <th class="col-md-1">Column 1</th>
         <th class="col-md-1">Column 2</th>
         <th class="col-md-1">Column 3</th>
         <th>Column ...</th>
         <th>Column n</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using <div > instead of table and you can easily fix the heading and also use display:table-cell;